# SQL Server 2014 Timeout from .NET but not from SSMS on simple table update

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, timeout, ssms

I get following error in my .NET App

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

when I simply run an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE Documents 
SET Status = 'ERROR', Message = 'MyMessage', TargetFile = 'Mypath' 
WHERE Id = 2379865
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014. I just happens in my .NET app. In SSMS it runs immediately.

I read something about set arithabort off but it didn't help.

I really don't know what to do.

Thanks you

Comment: Quite probably your application opens a transaction, which is not committed...

Comment: let us to see you code. c#? vb? winforms? asp.net?

Comment: if you want help, we need to see the code.

Comment: Use sql server profiler to debug: SSMS - Tools